# How to Remove UI container from Typescript UI

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

So, I'm using a open source UI for Chatgpt api.
It has some additional features like saving conversations in folders, and prompts.
I'm giving this open source version over to a non tech savvy family member with pre-prompts and API key because the interface is very clean, however there's one Advanced part I want to remove.

https://github.com/mckaywrigley/chatbot-ui

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to remove the UI container that has more advanced features like GPT MODEL - System Prompt, and Temperature.

However I'm having issues, I don't really understand this language very well or framework. Seems like multiple functions, or defined variables are linked throughout the source code folders. It was fairly easy to remove the buttons I just {*/ (notated them out)

However trying to put notes or remove syntax for the UI keeps coming back with errors in the debugging process, because it's like pre-defined as a **JSX element?**

**Can someone point me in the right direction?**

**What I did:** I figured out how to remove the buttons for API key, Google Search API, and Settings
It was fairly easy to remove the buttons I just {*/ (notated them out)

However trying to put notes or remove syntax for the UI keeps coming back with errors in the debugging process, because it's like pre-defined as a **JSX element?**

**Can someone point me in the right direction?**